# Disable HangFire server in specific environment (localhost)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

We have a scheduled HangFire job that runs every `4` hours. But hangfire floods the console with heart beat at every scheduled interval. That would be annoying when we run the application in local for developing new features (or) debugging existing code.
The heartbeat logs I was able to reduce by increasing the `HearbeatInterval` configuration.

The local application and hosted development environment application have same DB. The hosted development API already runs the recurring jobs. Hence I do not want to run them on our local machines(with API development) until unless it is necessary (Until unless I want to debug/test the scheduled jobs).

Since this is a quite common scenario for developers, I want to understand if HangFire provides a standard a way to achieve this?

Note: I have been though all the stackoverflow questions with `hangfire` tag and HangFire documentation to see if this is feasible with OOB solution with out custom code.

Comment: So... don't inject Hangfire into the service collection?

Comment: I want the HangFire to be part of my code and run on other environments like QA, Prod, staging. But not on local development machines. If need on local I should be able control with a configuration (If it exist)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant - do not inject it. It's quite easy to do with `if (environment.IsDevelopment())` for example

Comment: But we do have a development environment, where APIs are hosted for UI local development. That environment also considered as Development with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT => Development `.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Your comment gave me some more info that I can't use OOB approach, I have to define a boolean configuration to control the behavior.

Comment: Well... it's quite easy to define a new environment, don't take my words so explicitly, use your imagination a bit. Just add an if for the debugger being attached and set the environment to `Local` and check for `environment.IsEnvironment("local")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wasn't any OOB option from HangFire library.
As `Camilo Terevinto` mentioned, I was able to achieve this following work around.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // other service configuration goes here

  if (IsHangfireJobsAllowed())
  {
    // HangFire configuration
    var storage = HangFireJobs.GetHangFireStorageConnection(
        config["CosmosDBEndpoint"],
        config["CosmosDBAuthKey"],
        config["CosmosDBDatabaseName"]);
    
    // Add HangFire services.
    services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        //.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore })
        .UseStorage(storage));

    // Add the processing server as IHostedService
    services.AddHangfireServer();

    GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });
  }
  
  // other service configuration goes here
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
{
    // Other code goes here

    if (IsHangfireJobsAllowed())
    {
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");
        // Custom code to schedule the recurring jobs 
        HangFireJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJobs();
    }
    
    // Other code follows here
}

private bool IsHangfireJobsAllowed()
{
    // For QA and Prod env's add HangFire with out config dependency
    if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
        return true;
    // For Dev environment adding HangFire conditionally 
    // Ignoring return value since, the result will have 'true' 
    // only if the parsing is success and config has 'true'
    bool.TryParse(Configuration["HangFire:RunJobsOnDev"], out bool result);
    return result;
}
```

`Camilo Terevinto` and `DavidG`, thank you both of you.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html) say you can configure the logging levels directly in the `appsettings.json` file.

You can lower the number of messages for all Hangfire logs like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      ...
      "Hangfire": "Warning" //Only log warnings from Hangfire
    }
  }
}
```

But you may only want to exclude a specific subset of messages. I'm not sure exactly what namespace the heartbeat messages, but you can do something like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      ...
      "Hangfire": "Information", //Output information and above for all Hangfire logs
      "Hangfire.Server.ServerWatchdog": "Warning" // but only warnings for the 
                                                  // Hangfire.Server.ServerWatchdog namespace
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information on logging, but my question is more about how do I not run jobs on local  still having them in my code.